# Swift 4.2 if let fails with CMTime on Xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, core-media, xcode11

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 11.2 and building & running my app, Swift if let block is reporting failure which always used to work otherwise. Here is the code that fails.

```
public func remoteClient(receivedData data: [String : Any]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

  let params = data?["params"] as? [String:Any] 

  NSLog("Received image \(params!["timestamp"])")

  if let imgData = params?["image"] as? Data, let timeStamp = params?["timestamp"] as? CMTime
   {
           NSLog("Handling image response")
           handleImageResponse(imgData, timeStamp: timeStamp)

    } else {
           NSLog("Image response failed")
    }

}
```

And here is what gets printed on console

```
  2019-11-02 23:47:52.342324+0530 MyApp [312:9779] Received image Optional(CMTime: {34515835925000/1000000000 = 34515.836})
  2019-11-02 23:47:52.343251+0530 MyApp[312:9779] Image response failed
```

Removing the check for CMTime in 'if let' solves the issue, but then how do I extract CMTime from params dictionary?

1. What has suddenly changed when building with Xcode 11.2, I wonder?
2. params!["timestamp"] is printing CMTime in the console, what fails in the if let assignment then?

And it's CMTime that is failing, I tried this:

```
   if let imgData = params?["image"] as? Data, let timeStamp = params?["timestamp"] as? Any {

      let time = timeStamp as! CMTime

   }
```

And I get a crash:

```
 Could not cast value of type 'CMTimeAsValue' (0x10ce321d8) to '__C.CMTime' (0x2355bab00).
```

Comment: You have like 5 failable conditions in a single if let statement. Are you sure the whole architecture of your app is not terrible?

Comment: Regardless of architecture, why is check for timestamp failing?

Comment: According to the log output params["image"] can be cast directly to CMTime. I the Data cast is almost certainly failing. Then again, you could easily figure this out on your own by using the debugger in Xcode.

Comment: No, it's not!!! CMTime is nil!

Comment: I added more details to show it is CMTime failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the time is stored in the dictionary as an `NSValue` wrapping a  `CMTime`. In that case the correct way to extract the time is

```
if let val = params["timestamp"] as? NSValue {
    let time = val.timeValue
    // ...
}
```

See also [`NSValue(time:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1388561-init) and [`NSValue.timeValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1388151-timevalue).

Comment: It works! I tried typecasting it to CMTimeValue that failed too.